# Perl regular expression named groups array

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to capture named groups in an array.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $text = 'My aunt is on vacation and eating some apples and banana';
$text =~ m/(?<Letter>A.)/img ;
print Dumper(%-) ;
```

output is

```
$VAR1 = 'Letter';
$VAR2 = [
          'au'
        ];
```

but I would expect or actually was hoping that any occurrence will appear in the array.

```
$VAR1 = 'Letter';
$VAR2 = [
          'au',
          'ac',
          'at',
          'an',
          'at',
          'an'
        ];
```

Any chance to get all groups in one array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either run the `m//g` in list context to get all the matching substrings (but without the capture names), or you need to match in a loop:

```perl
my @matches = $text =~ m/(?<Letter>A.)/img ;
print Dumper(\@matches) ;
```

or

```perl
while ($text =~ m/(?<Letter>A.)/img) {
       print Dumper(\%+) ;
}
```

Comment: Champion: what a magic in this code +1. How its printing with letter `'Letter' => 'an'` Could you please explain the second code?

Comment: `%-` is needed when there are several groups of the same name. `%+` is simpler when there's only one group per name. Using a reference (i.e. \\) in Dumper for a hash or array prints the structure rather than printing individual values (or keys and values).

Comment: But if %- is capturing multiple groups of same name and giving an array for what do I need to run with foreach over it again. Confusing and not logical to me. But thanks for you answer. Will create a function retuning the array I require.

Comment: @EricStolz: `%-` is for cases like `/a(?<letter>.).*?a(?<letter>.)/`, where the same named capture group appears several times in the regex, not when it matches several times. The latter case must be solved with a loop.